# iOS: Load Images.xcassets when Build in first time because I have a many image

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcasset

I need to load Images.xcassets when Build in first time like a game on mobile(large file) please help me or recommend best way .

Answer (score 1):

You need to load images async way. If you have large files, there will be considerable slowness in your app, if you are doing all in the main thread. If you are new to this kind of things, I highly recommend using SDWebImage library. It does all those things for you.

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Comment: thank you for answered but I can't use async for load  because  image is ul such as button image, tab Image i need load all Images.xcassets for image iPhone and iPad interface image  :)